# Trying to deploy postgresql database to Azure from pgadmin and get SSL Certificate_Verify_Failed error

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssl, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to deploy my postgresql v16 database to Azure via pgadmin v4.83.  I start the Register -> Deploy Cloud Instance wizard and enter my tenantid and then press the "Click here to Authenticate yourself to Microsoft Azure" button.  After a few seconds it returns with the following error:
[image]

I tried downloading the SSL public certificate from Azure and setting the server parameters in pgadmin as below but still had the error.  Please help.

Azure Postgresql Networking Instructions for cert download:
[image]

The learn more link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-connect-tls-ssl

PgAdmin server Parameters:
[image: pgadmin server parameters:]

Comment: Only Microsoft can replace their expired certificate.

Comment: So are you saying that the DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem that I downloaded from Azure is the problem, not anything I am doing or not doing in pgadmin?

Comment: Not the certification authority certificate is the problem, but the server certificate that the database server uses.

Comment: The pem you showed us configuring appears to be for the database itself, while the cert being complained about seems to be for some azure web app or something, not the database.  What azure public cert did you download? Please link to whatever instructions you followed.

Comment: @jjanes I added a screenshot of part of the screen where I downloaded the cert from Azure and the learn more link related to it.

Comment: The cert you downloaded is specific to PostgreSQL, while the error seems to be about a different cert, one used upstream of that to establish something like an "ssh tunnel" or VPN link to azure.  Can you use other (non-PostgreSQL) features of azure?

Comment: @jjanes, I can use other features of Azure.  I can even connect to my Azure Postgres server via pgAdmin.  I just can't use the deploy wizard in pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.  I managed to get a solution with the help of @PratikLad who pointed me in the right direction. In case it helps anyone else, all I did was install the Azure Cli SDK and then I was able to run the wizard using the Azure Cli option.

Answer (score 0):

> I start the Register -> Deploy Cloud Instance wizard and enter my tenant id and then press the "Click here to Authenticate yourself to Microsoft Azure" button. After a few seconds it returns with the error

As you mentioned in the question you are getting error when you are trying authenticating to your azure tenant

The issue is with your certificate which python libraries are using when you authenticate with Azure CLI, some part of certificate might miss or if you are using Azure CLI with a self-signed certificate behind a proxy that snoops on traffic.

To resolve this, you can try workaround given here by @vandre in below similar [GitHub thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26420).

Also see this [GitHub Document](https://github.com/jiasli/azure-notes/blob/master/cli/proxy-cert-win.md) to use Azure CLI behind a proxy.